# Easy Riddles #3 I tried to kill you 3 times <3

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A girl shoots her boyfriend, but he doesn't die. She then holds him underwater for ten minutes straight, but he still doesn't die. Finally, she hangs him to the roof, and he is still alive. How is this possible?

Comment: @Randal'Thor sorry about that...I guess I keep on thinking that everything's a riddle :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> She's developing and putting up a photo she took of him

Comment: Yesss @Phylyp strikes again

Answer (score 3):

> She took a photo (photo shoot) then in the old days, you had to put it underwater, so he didn't die, she put the picture in the water. Then of course, she had to dry the photo so she hung it outside.